# Find variable value

Tags: javascript, math

I have some inputs in my app: `<_input code/> + <_input code/> = <_input code/>`.

Let's imagine first input name is `a`, appropriately second and third inputs' names are `b` and `c`. I filled my inputs:
`7 + x = 12`

Is there any way to calculate `x` value?

What do I want from my script:

It finds variable in inputs' values.

1. It checks all fields of my form filled properly.
2. It finds variable in inputs' values.
3. From given information script calculates value of variable.

How many inputs will be doesn't matter.  I just want to find value of `x`. Is there any library to do this?

```
function calculcateA(b,c){
   return c-b;
}

if(inputA === 'x'){
    alert(calculateA(inputB,inputC));
}
```

And so on... there is nothing wrong with this functions, but I want to automate this proccess like WolframAplha.

Comment: Default question: **What do you tried**? Shortly, yes, it's possible.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I tried manually find variable value: for my situation I used 3 function - calculateA(), calculateB(), calculateC()

Comment: Nice, then post they here. So you can say whats wrong with them and guide you on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing for you, I guess would be to find some library for solving equations. If you are in need to solve bigger sets of equations then maybe something related to linear algebra.
Can't really tell you an exact solution so you will have to search for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should solve the problem.

```
function calculate() {
    var varIndex = -1;

    //Ensure that at least two three arguements are passed
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        throw "You need at least three parameters to make an equation";
    }

    //Make sure that there is only one variable
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(arguments[i])) {
            if (varIndex != -1) {
                throw "You can't have two variables";
                return;
            }
            varIndex = i;
       }
    }

    //If variable has been found
    if (varIndex != -1) {
        var answer = 0;
        //If variable is at the last position, add all constants
        if (varIndex == types.length - 1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length - 1; j++) {
                answer = answer + j;
            }
        } else {
            //Otherwise Deduct all values from the last
            answer = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            for (var k = 0; k < arguments.length - 1; k++) {
                if (k == varIndex) { continue; }
                answer = answer - j;
            }
        }

        //Return Result
        return { variable: arguments[varIndex], answer: answer };
    }
    else {
        throw "You need at least one variable";
        return;
    }
}
```

You would use the above as follows:

```
var a = document.querySelector("input[name=a]");
var b = document.querySelector("input[name=b]");
var c = document.querySelector("input[name=c]");

var calcBtn = document.getElementById("calculate");


calcBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    try {
        var result = calculate(a.value, b.value, c.value);
        console.log("The value of " + result.variable + " is " + result.answer);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```